# Repeat substrings N times

Tags: c#, regex

I receive series of strings followed by non-negative numbers, e.g. `"a3"`. I have to print on the console each string repeated `N` times (**uppercase**) where `N` is a number in the input. In the example, the result: `"AAA"`. As you see, I have tried to get the numbers from the input and I think it's working fine. Can you help me with the repeating?

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
//input = "aSd2&5s@1"
MatchCollection matched = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+");
List<int> repeatsCount = new List<int>();

foreach (Match match in matched)
{
    int repeatCount = int.Parse(match.Value);
    repeatsCount.Add(repeatCount);
}
//repeatsCount: [2, 5, 1]
//expected output: ASDASD&&&&&S@ ("aSd" is converted to "ASD" and repeated twice;
// "&" is repeated 5 times; "s@" is converted to "S@" and repeated once.)
```

For example, if we have "aSd**2**&**5**s@**1**":
`"aSd"` is converted to `"ASD"` and repeated **twice**; `"&"` is repeated **5 times**; `"s@"` is converted to `"S@"` and **repeated once**.

Comment: I can't do it myself and that's the reason why I'm posting here. If it was a homework problem, I would connect with my teachers.

Answer (score 3):

Let the pattern include *two groups*: `value` to repeat and how many `times` to repeat:

```
@"(?<value>[^0-9]+)(?<times>[0-9]+)"
```

Then we can operate with these *groups*, say, with a help of *Linq*:

```
  string source = "aSd2&5s@1";

  string result = string.Concat(Regex
    .Matches(source, @"(?<value>[^0-9]+)(?<times>[0-9]+)")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .SelectMany(match => Enumerable                        // for each match
       .Repeat(match.Groups["value"].Value.ToUpper(),      // repeat "value"
               int.Parse(match.Groups["times"].Value))));  // "times" times 

  Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
ASDASD&&&&&S@
```

**Edit:** Same idea *without Linq*:

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(source, @"(?<value>[^0-9]+)(?<times>[0-9]+)")) {
    string value = match.Groups["value"].Value.ToUpper();
    int times = int.Parse(match.Groups["times"].Value);

    for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i)
      sb.Append(value);
  }

  string result = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract substring and how often it should be repeated with this regex:

```
(?<content>.+?)(?<count>\d+)
```

Now you can use a `StringBuilder` to create output string. Full code:

```
var input = "aSd2&5s@1";
var regex = new Regex("(?<content>.+?)(?<count>\\d+)");
var matches = regex.Matches(input).Cast<Match>();
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    var count = int.Parse(match.Groups["count"].Value);
    for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        sb.Append(match.Groups["content"].Value.ToUpper());
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Output is

> ASDASD&&&&&S@

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without LINQ

i tried to keep the solution so it would be similar to yours

```
string input = "aSd2&5s@1";
var matched = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+");
var builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Match match in matched)
{
     string stingToDuplicate = input.Split(Char.Parse(match.Value))[0];
     input = input.Replace(stingToDuplicate, String.Empty).Replace(match.Value, String.Empty);
      for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(match.Value); i++)
      {
                  builder.Append(stingToDuplicate.ToUpper());
      }
 }
```

and finally   `Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());`
which result `ASDASD&&&&&S@`

Comment: Well it woul work but _without LINQ_ in text and with `.First()` in code it looks strange :)

Comment: @AleksAndreev i don't see `.First()` anywhere in my code, do you? :)

Comment: Now I don't. But it was there [in first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55513920/1). Now you removed it, so I have no questions to you anymore

Answer (score 1):

My solution is same as others with slight differences :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication107
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "aSd2&5s@1";
            string pattern1 = @"[a-zA-z@&]+\d+";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern1);

            string output = "";
            foreach(Match match in matches.Cast<Match>().ToList())
            {
                string pattern2 = @"(?'string'[^\d]+)(?'number'\d+)";
                Match match2 = Regex.Match(match.Value, pattern2);
                int number = int.Parse(match2.Groups["number"].Value);
                string str = match2.Groups["string"].Value;

                output += string.Join("",Enumerable.Repeat(str.ToUpper(), number));
            }
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple program. No linq nothing, simple `string` and `for` loop.

```
string input = "aSd2&5s@1";
char[] inputArray = input.ToCharArray();
string output = "";

string ab = "";
foreach (char c in inputArray)
{
    int x;
    string y;
    if(int.TryParse(c.ToString(), out x))
    {
        string sb = "";
        ab = ab.ToUpper();
        for(int i=0;i<b;i++)
        {
           sb += ab;
        }
        ab = "";
        output += sb;
    }
    else
    {
        ab += c;
    }
}
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ab))
{
    output += ab.ToUpper();
}
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Hope it helps.